# Google Analytics User-Id view isn't picking up GTM userId

Tags: analytics

I cant see any data in my created View, I've tested with:

1. `ga('create', 'Tracking Id', 'auto');`
2. `ga('set', 'userId', 'email@test.com');`
3. 

```
`ga('create', 'Tracking Id', 'auto', {
  userId: "email@test.com"
});`
```

But none of above works